# How to create a datetimefiled that keeps the last edited time in django

Tags: python, django

I'm toying around in `django` trying to understand its philosophy, and I tried to create a last modified entry. I place this in my code:

```
slide_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
last_date = models.DateTimeField('last modified',auto_now=True)
def __str__(self):
    out = 'title: {}\n last modified: {}'.format(
            self.slide_title,
            type(self.last_date)
            )
    return out
```

But when I start a `shell` (using `python manage.py shell`) I get the following

```
In [2]: from pressent.models import Slide

In [3]: Slide.objects.all()
Out[3]: 
[<Slide: title: title
last modified: <type 'NoneType'>>]
```

Why isn't it a DateTimeField?

Comment: How did you create the object? Try calling `slide.save()` on it. `auto_now` should set the current datetime when the object's save method is called.

Answer (score 1):

You did an `auto_now=True`. But that works only when `Model.save()` method is called. To populate the `DateTimeField` at the time of creation, you need to add another attribute `auto_now_add=True`.

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you correctly, is this undoable without saving the ``Slide`` or should adding the field ``auto_now_add=True`` should solve this? At any rate, I updated my code, and saved  a new slide, with the same result.

Comment: Your existing rows will not change. To see the new changes, add a new entry in `Slide` model. The `DateTimeField` should auto-populate.